# PHP works on page, but not on other from the same site

Tags: php, html, function

Im new on PHP trying to understand why a PHP function works on a page but does not on other from the same site.

Works here: http://soymusico.net/perfil/64-federico-barenboin
But dosen not here: http://soymusico.net/comunidad/search/field?FIELD_CITY=Buenos%20Aires

```
<li><b>Nacionalidad</b>
        <?php  $city = CFactory::getUser($profile->id)->getInfo('FIELD_CITY'); ?>
        <?php  $country = CFactory::getUser($profile->id)->getInfo('FIELD_COUNTRY'); ?>
         <div><a href="comunidad/search/field?FIELD_CITY=<?php echo $city;?>"><?php echo $city; ?></a>,
              <a href="comunidad/search/field?FIELD_COUNTRY=<?php echo $country;?>"><?php echo $country; ?></a>
         </div>
</li>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you included the file in which the function is declared in the second page?

Comment: Check your includes, and take a look on the php_error.log of your server. Could be really helpful.

Comment: Are us sure that connection to DB is made successfully. Kindly check connection to DB

Answer (score 1):

PHP is working, otherwise you have seen the html page display the `<?php` tag in the body.
What is not working is either:

1. the CFactory method
2. or your database connection, that reads those
   fields.

Im betting its the CFactory method. Are you including all the necessary libraries?